# Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ExecProcess The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In some of my servers (not all of them), I get the following message inside sqlcmd:

========================================

PS C:\Users> sqlcmd -S 10.10.1.112 -U cheritia
Password:

1> select getdate()

2> go

2019-01-30 16:06:11.667

(1 rows affected)

1> ed

Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ExecProcess (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).

========================================

In my typical installation, I use "vim" as an editor inside sqlcmd, I have tried other editors, they all fail.

The error is the same in powershell or Windows cmd.

Any clue?

Comment: You will probably get more traction if you research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check if you have the same version of `sqlcmd` in servers that work and servers that don't work. My version of SQLCMD fails as well, and it does so because it attempts to execute `C:\"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c <your SQLCMDEDITOR>` (where the initial ``C:\`` is the current directory, where you started SQLCMD). Obviously this fails, less obvious is why it's doing this.